# MalformedInputException when reading file using Apache FileUtils

Tags: java, java-11, charset

`FileUtils.readLines(attribFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`  This line is giving the error: `Method threw java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException`
What could be the reason for this?
Is it because the File could contain characters that are not supported by UTF_8?
But when I check the JSON response of the HTTP GET request from which the file is built I don't see any special characters. I just see `, - . \n :`
Any ideas on how do I debug this further?

**Some Things I tried:**
There is no error when I use `FileUtils.readLines(attribFile)`. This seems to be working properly. Although the function is deprecated.

**Thing that worked:**
To generate the input file I was using `PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(attribFile)` I changed this to `PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(attribFile),"UTF-8")`  and it worked fine.

But this really gave me a headache. I am used to coding like `PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(attribFile)` without specifying the charset. This seems to be a bug/code quality issue on the methods that it allows to create an object without specifying the charset. Probably that is why `FileUtils.readLines` is deprecated without specifying the charset.
Looking for thoughts on the above
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the input file *is* UTF-8? You need to specify the actual encoding of the file you're reading.

Comment: *Is it because the File could contain characters that are not supported by UTF_8?* No, it is because the file is not encoded as UTF-8. It's encoded with your system default encoding. Incidentally, you don't need 3rd party libraries for your code. The normal JRE will suffice *I just see , - . \n :* That's the punctuation - what about the letters?

Comment: As far as your recent edit is concerned - which version of Java are you using?

Comment: `PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(attribFile),"UTF-8")` I modified the code that generated the file to this and it worked. But that's really a problem because most of the functions allow to create objects without specifying the Charset. One could easily get into these types of issues. Any recommendations to avoid such issues? Also, I noticed that FileUtils.readLines is deprecated without the charset. That's interesting. Could that be called an improvement over the code quality and avoid people landing up in unnecessary bugs like the one I faced.

Comment: `try(PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(Path.of(attribFile))) { ... }` will write it as UTF-8 by default. There's no universal way to detect encoding automatically such that your read/writes are always correct, unfortunately

Comment: Smilarly, `List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines(Path.of(attribFile));` will read as UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote

> This seems to be a bug/code quality issue on the methods that it allows to create an object without specifying the charset.

and the simple answer is that you are right, though this is a long standing, well known issue. So any code audit tool should be able to warn you about this.

Further, the issue has been addressed in Java 18. Starting with this version, [all methods without a specified encoding will consistently use UTF-8 by default](https://openjdk.org/jeps/400).

As [mentioned in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76412828/#comment134742315_76412828) [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76412828/#comment134742632_76412828), you can use the methods in [`java.nio.file.Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html) to read and write text without the need for a 3rd party library and the methods in this class use UTF-8 when no character encoding has been specified, in all Java versions.

Comment: *and the simple answer is that you are right, though this is a long standing, well known issue* Why would that really be a *bug* when all it will be using is the default encoding, no other having been specified?

Comment: @g00se it said “bug/code quality issue” and I considered it a “code quality issue”. Even one that has been addressed by the Java developers. Though, before they addressed it, I used to consider it a quality issue of the code using the method/constructor.

Comment: @Holger could you suggest any good code audit tool that I can use with Intellij?

Comment: It [has a built-in check](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/list-of-java-inspections.html#internationalization) you just have to activate it. Look for “*Implicit usage of platformcodes default charset*”

Comment: Personally I don't see how this defaulting to UTF-8 is going to work. There will probably be a lot of Windows users wondering why their characters are looking weird, just like there were before ;)

Comment: @g00se you’d be surprised how many Windows tools nowadays deal with UTF-8 automatically. However, this is of course a change, developers might have to deal with when migrating from an older to a newer Java version. At least, `java.io` and `java.nio.files` now have the same behavior, which is a huge step forward.

Comment: Right. tbh, I haven't used it *at all* for a couple of years now and, on a regular basis, probably for as many decades

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your problem is most likely that your file is not encoded in UTF-8 but in some other charset. However, if you can read your file successfully here is a diagnostic tool that can help you. There is a Utility that can convert any string to unicode sequence and vise-versa. If you convert the text of your file into inicodes you can see what numeric codes are used to encode your text and thus you may find out which charset is used the utility class is called `StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder` is available as part of MgntUtils Open Source library written and maintained by me. Here is an example of usage:

```
result = "Hello World";
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence(result);
System.out.println(result);
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString(result);
System.out.println(result);
```

The output of this code is:

```
\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064
Hello World
```

The library can be found at [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils/1.5.0.2/jar) or at [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt) It comes as maven artifact and with sources and javadoc

Here is javadoc for the class [StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.html)

Comment: …and if you don’t want to add a 3rd party library to your codebase for that, you can use [these one liners](https://tio.run/##jZBBawIxEIXv@yuGhUICblAQoYgF6aU9FAQPPVgP6W5cs002YTIrFvG3b6eu9VrnEubN472PNPqgi6b66nvrY0CChgXVkXUKTW2OaqWJDLbzLIvdp7MllE6nBG/attkpA7iqiTTxcwi2As83sSa0bb3ZgsY6STb@mgEGGdCkzhEsIH8xzgV4D@iqfH6x3G7XalUGH60zIle5VF5TuTcoBpdkyuh0aZbOCY9QPF0b1C4gW0X@wdM9jKfHfATCtiQ9qhpDF4Xk4MqsAotLEmMp5dC//k5kvAodqchR5Nq/sv/4Ll1iMy4edbHbnqaj2Vneg/y816hLzlIUBnzx2hJ/P6qoMRlexA17Ikcwmd1Je87OWd//AA)…

Comment: @holger this is interesting but won't work for foreign languages especially with non-latinic letters such as Russian, Arabic Hebrew, Chineese Japaneese etc

Comment: [What exactly doesn’t work?](https://tio.run/##jZHBSsMwHMbvfYo/BSGBLWwwBjIUhicPwmDHuUPssi4zbUqajskY2L3C8CAo4sGDKAiKICj4Btqdepa@gG9Q4zp3dckh/L98fN8vZEhHtDzsHec59wKpNAyNQCLNBVHMZWPSoloz5TcsK4iOBHfAETQM4YBy35pYACs11FSbYyR5Dzxzh9pacd/tdIEqN8TG@GsGKGRQLIyEhh2wk/fFafKSPCbPixl8vZ1/vJp9/zmD9Da9SM/SS/i@unmCLJ5ns3kW32XxdRY/2I1l2jpmRUkc6QVcMGQTGxOPamfAFCpc2DwoENRhTSGQp6C8u4IhfamMFdmHZkVbldrYLgHivsaeIq6SUYCwCe6xljRiU6MKxrjob5@EmnlERpoEJkoL/6/sP75lF@pUytu03O9OaqX6FG@CvDegijomi2hZ4KN9X5ufUiSgKmRmQGvsKi5Btb4h7dSaWnn@Aw)

Comment: I didn't try yet, but it seems that when you translate the code back to letter you only translate last 2 digits. So any string \u00XX will work but any unicode with first 2 digits that are not 00 will not work.

Comment: You just have to click on the link; it does already run the program and demonstrates that it works.